# Explanation of the proverb "Beauty is only skin deep...."

Tags: proverbs

Can someone help me understand the following proverb?

> beauty is only skin deep but ugliness cuts clean through to the bone

I know it means something like true beauty is on the inside, but I want to understand it more "deeply"

Comment: This is rather off-topic as it doesn't fall into the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq) categories of Word choice and usage; Grammar; Etymology; Dialect; Pronunciation; Spelling and punctuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have often heard the expression that 'beauty is only skin deep'.  I have not heard the other part to this expression: 'ugliness cuts clean through to the bone'.

If you were to paraphrase this saying, you could say: 'beauty is superficial but ugliness is much more deeply rooted'.

As you know, beauty can easily be destroyed but it is much more difficult to change something that is ugly.

Comment: Beauty is only skin deep, but this is just the right depth. No man wants a woman who has a pretty pancreas, a gorgeous gall bladder or a lovely liver.